# reshape data in R long to wide NAs

Tags: r, reshape

I have data in long format that I have successfully attempted to reshape into wide, using the reshape function.

```
IntComm2
     ID period  OBJPLAY1    AggRJA12 MISTOT1 PCFPTLR2 PCFPTPP2
1   109      1      -0.02788542       8       36       59
2   109      2      -0.02788542       8       36       59
3   109      3      -0.02788542       8       36       59
4   109      4      -0.02788542       8       36       59
5   113      1      -0.92693317       2       53       32
6   113      2      -0.92693317       2       53       32
7   113      3      -0.92693317       2       53       32
8   113      4      -0.92693317       2       53       32
9   114      1      -0.02788542      NA       49       27
10  114      2      -0.02788542      NA       49       27
11  114      3      -0.02788542      NA       49       27
12  114      4      -0.02788542      NA       49       27
13  120      1      -0.74213524       5       32       22
14  120      2      -0.74213524       5       32       22
15  120      3      -0.74213524       5       32       22
16  120      4      -0.74213524       5       32       22
17  131      1       0.49177857      NA       36       30
18  131      2       0.49177857      NA       36       30
19  131      3       0.49177857      NA       36       30


IntCommWide2<-reshape(data=IntComm2,
  timevar="period",
  idvar=c("ID", "OBJPLAY1", "AggRJA12", "MISTOT1", "PCFPTLR2", "PCFPTPP2"),
  direction="wide")
```

However, when I check my data, any rows with NAs were listwise deleted, so I am losing data for ~15 participants! Why is R doing this and what can I do to keep my NAs?

```
IntCommWide2
     ID     OBJPLAY1    AggRJA12 MISTOT1 PCFPTLR2 PCFPTPP2
1   109 -0.44822774 -0.02788542       8       36       59
5   113 -0.44118187 -0.92693317       2       53       32
9   114  0.16460363 -0.02788542      NA       49       27
13  120 -1.24245042 -0.74213524       5       32       22
21  134  0.89983707 -0.93672108      12       76       76
```

114 made it through with an NA, but see how 131 is just missing? All of the rest of IDs with NAs in any variable seem to be gone.

Comment: `reshape` is not part of the `reshape2` package. You are probably looking for melt/dcast

Comment: reshape is a function that is generally available in R.

Comment: Also I wanted to note that R usually treats NA's as null values when computing. So if it drops, there should not be a big deal. Unless of course, in your data NA means anything other than "Not Available" or "Null Attribute". If that is the case, then a good suggestion would be to rename it to something else and rerun the shape command.

Comment: It is list wise deleting participants when there are only NAs in a single variable. As in, I may be fine with dropping them in analyses that include that variable, but I'd like them to still be in the data frame so I can use them in analyses that include other variables for which they have data.

Comment: Without reproducible data this question is incomplete. Consider editing.

Comment: @Micheal I am presuming participants = observations. In this case, NA = Null or Empty values. For example, if I have an excel sheet that has "NA" 's in  its data (census for example, codes empty values as NA instead of white spaces). Then it wouldn't matter if these were dropped as I imported them into R. But if they meant something like NA=North America, I would have to either create an exception for them or rename them to anything other than NA.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Ditto. At best, my comments are a guess to your situation OP.

Comment: @nongkrong Good point. I didn't think of it this way. The first part of my comment was what NA might mean based on the data source. The second part was once it was imported to R, if it will have any affect on any analysis conducted on it. But a good point you mention that I forgot. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have edited to include data.

Comment: @Micheal you explicitly said you were using the `reshape2` package

Comment: @Riorank, Yes, NA is Null in this case, but I need the data sheet to reflect that said ID has no value for that variable, but still has values for other variables.

Comment: @Senor O, It was a typo in my first post and I have edited.

Comment: Can you revise your input and output tables? I am having a little trouble associating which variables goes with which columns.

Comment: Are you sure this is a reshaping problem?  Your example makes it look  like you want to filter the dataset to the unique values for all the variables except `period` in each `ID` rather than taking info in rows and putting it in columns/going long to wide.

Comment: @aosmith One thing I am noticing in the output is that ID 131 is not being processed. The only difference I see is that it only has 3 observations under OBJPLAY1

Comment: Yes, that is my point- that 131 (and other IDs that you cannot see here) are being deleted. There are actually 4 observations for 131, I just didn't copy that far down. The dataset is much bigger and I have reduced it to a few IDs and variables here to explain my problem. I only have one variable for which there is a separate value for all 4 periods, so I needed to split that variable up -e.g. Xtime1 Xtime2 Xtime3 Xtime4. That variable isn't pictured here.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just replace NA-s with -1 or 0 and then reshape?

Comment: If I do this, how do I make them NAs after reshaping so as not to effect analysis?

Comment: @Micheal Back to the raw data. Where is it from? You said that NA = Null in the question comments. But is this actually reflected in the raw data files? Or was this what R put into the blanks when you imported it to R? Another way to see this is does NA equal the words "NA" or "     " (blankspace) in the raw data file.

Comment: @doker I believe this would work (arbitrarily assigning values to the NA's) As long as it does not affect the output. A way to test this is to replacing (for example) the values of "MIST01" with "2" for ID rows 1-4 and see if it has a different reshape output.

Comment: The raw data file (a csv) says NA. When I import the data, the NA's are reflected accurately as NA.

Comment: I edited so that the columns are more clear.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks. If this is the case, then I would like to ask what your outputs looks like when you arbitrarily assign numbers to the NA's with observations that currently are being shaped correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to say "keep nas" when I enter my reshape command? I've tried na.rm=FALSE, but I get errors

Comment: na.rm=FALSE is only when the raw data has "     " (blankspace). Since you said that the raw data files has "NA". R is not reading it as a vector (I may have used the wrong term here) but rather a string. Hence ID 131 not being processed.

Comment: @Riorank When I change NAs to 999, IDs aren't deleted. Everything is reflected. I have searched and see that I can use this code to rename 999 to NAs.
    WideTest$ADOSDSMAD1[WideTest$ADOSDSMAD1==999]<-NA
This workaround works. Thanks!